# When i am sending Email from Batch Class, why i am not getting email tracking in HTML Email Status?

Tags: email-template, apex-email-service, email-alert

When I am sending emails from Trigger, I am getting email tracking on "HTML Status" related list but on the other hand When i am sending Email from Batch Class, why i am not getting email tracking in HTML Email Status?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I think the answer might be that you're inserting EmailMessage records with the correct ParentId in one the trigger context, and not in your batch class. Please [edit] your post to include relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're either not saving the activity (setSaveAsActivity=false), or you're using a plain text template. There's no fundamental reason why triggers would track the email while batchable classes would not.